# PowerShell - Taking Action Based Off of User Input?

Tags: powershell, user-input

I want to request user input via PromptForChoice and then, based on what they select, do a certain action.

In my code I have three options: Laptop, Tablet, and Workstation . If the user selects one, I want to do a certain action as opposed to the other actions assigned to the other options.

In the code, I do not really understand the line containing the decision variable, or what the number 1 means either after $choices. I have put asterisks around the parts of the code I don't understand.

I do not know how to assign certain actions to one button. The first part of code is what I want to do but isn't working, and the last part is the actual script.

```
$decision = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $question, $choices, **1**)
if ($decision -eq **Laptop**)
```

---

```
$title    = 'PC Type Selection'
$question = 'Select Object Type'
$choices  = '&Laptop','&Tablet' ,'&Workstation'

$decision = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $question, $choices, 1)
if ($decision -eq 0) {
Write-Host 'confirmed'
} else {
Write-Host 'cancelled'
}
```

Comment: There is a bit of a misunderstanding here, I believe you're testing this code from Powershell ISE which is why you're seeing a popup with 3 buttons. If this is intended for users, you will most likely run this using just Powershell CLI aka powershell.exe and you will not see a popup from there using `$host.UI.prompt...`.

Comment: This is a very common task for any language. There tons of examples all over the web showing specifically how to do what you are after, as well as many posts right here on SO. Just use the SO search box above or your favorite search engine. As well as many videos showing this and how to do it on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell+getting+user+input+popup) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell+%27prompt+for+choice%27). You set 3 choices but you are not asking for any of them. You're only showing you exit the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ISE or the console host, notwithstanding; you don't get back a string from this code. You get an array/index number.

```
$title    = 'PC Type Selection'
$question = 'Select Object Type'
$choices  = '&Laptop','&Tablet' ,'&Workstation'

<#
Using PowerShell's variable squeezing to assign the results and
output to screen at the same time.

This, not a requirement, just a demo of how to see your variable 
content on use.
#>
($decision = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $question, $choices, 1))
# Results
<#
0
#>

# Results
<#
1
#>

# Results
<#
2
#>
```

So, you need to ask for that number, then branch to whatever else you'd want to do, using conditional logic. Multiple or nested if/then/else, try/catch. or switch statement.

```
$title    = 'PC Type Selection'
$question = 'Select Object Type'
$choices  = '&Laptop','&Tablet' ,'&Workstation'

$decision = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $question, $choices, 1)

switch ($decision)
{
    0 {'You selected Laptop'}
    1 {'You selected Tablet'}
    2 {'You selected Workstation'}
    Default {}
}

# Results
<#
You selected Laptop
#>

# Results
<#
You selected Tablet
#>

# Results
<#
You selected Workstation
#>
```